# "Who" usage in interrogative form

Tags: verb-agreement, formality, relative-clauses, syntactic-analysis, relative-pronouns

When using "who" in a question, which is correct:

Is it I who has erred?
Is it I who have erred?

The latter seems correct by test (take out who), but the former seems correct by question form (singular, but take out I).

Comment: **COMPARE:** *Who’s right here? Am I right here? Is it I who **?am** right here?*

Comment: Traditionally, *It is I who am here* is correct.  However, one is more likely to encounter *It is me who is here* nowadays.